# Что не так в запросе?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_created) AS days_live,DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_tracked) AS days_tracked, if(`withdrawal`='instant','автоматическая',if(`withdrawal`='manual','по запросу')) as `withdrawal` FROM `hyips` ORDER BY `rating` ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором if отсутствует 3-й параметр

Comment: спс, правда, поторопился, уже сам нашел